# 16.04.1 LiveCD briefly boots into TTY1, then black screen; TTY1 asks for username/password

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, login

I run a dual boot w/ Windows 7. Recently, I installed Windows 7 Service Pack 1 which, surprise surprise, screwed up Grub and left Windows the default OS w/ no option to boot into Ubuntu. This is usually a pretty easy fix (boot-repair), but the problem is I can't get a LiveCD that boots.

When I boot from a LiveCD usb, the screen flicks to TTY1, then to a black screen. The screen stays black unless I press `ctrl + alt + F1` to get back to TTY1, where I'm then asked for a username and password. I've tried `ubuntu` with a blank password and this does not work.

I'm using [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) image. I've tried with a fresh USB multiple times. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: To start solving the issue you probably need to post `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`… But, as the actual problem you need to solve is to just restore grub, [you can do it from the tty perfectly fine](http://askubuntu.com/a/88432/266507), there's no need at configuring Internet, and alike. If you really need Live CD/USB, you could also try to boot from Fedora with Gnome, because… err… I struggle to say specifically, just a number of trivia tends to be more stable.

Comment: Ah, yeah, blank password didn't work. Well, in this case give a try to another LiveCD. At the very least, where password is working

Answer (score 0):

Try using [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) in Windows to adjust the boot order -- move the `ubuntu` item to the top of the boot list. This *should* fix the problem; however, be aware that there are buggy EFIs that may forget boot entries or have problems with re-ordering them. There's also a slim chance that Windows has deleted the Ubuntu entry, in which case it will have to be re-created.